# How we can solve two lines of this algorithm in $o(n^2)$?

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

Given $n=2k$ pairs of points  $P=\{(p_1,q_1),(p_2,q_2),\dots,(p_k,q_k)\}$  in the plane. Also, let $d(.)$ return distance between two points.

Now, our goal is to act as bellow:

1. For each $(p_i,q_i)$ repeat bellow loop that  partition points into $A$ and $B$ as follow :
2. Create empty array $A$ and set $A=A\cup p_i$. Now we want to find $k-1$ points such that we put those points into $A$, and distance between each points in $A$ be at most $d(p_i,q_i)$ and $A$ doesn't contains pair of points $(p_t,q_t)$ for $t=1..k$.
3. Create empty array $B$ and set $B=B\cup p_i$. Now we want to find $k-1$ points such that we put those points into $B$, and distance between each points in $B$ be at most $d(p_i,q_i)$ and $B$ doesn't contains pair of points $(p_t,q_t)$ for $t=1..k$.
4. If such a partition is possible then return it.

Is there any idea or data structure to solve line $2-3$ in $o(n^2)$?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  I don't know how it could be possible that $A=A\cup p_i$.  I don't know what you mean by "each points".  I don't understand how $A$ is constructed.  I don't know what you mean by "such partition" or "possible".  I think you're going to have to explain your question more clearly.

Comment: Apparently, English is your second language. Could Google Translate do better?

Comment: @JohnL. I edit my question, could you read it again, thank you.